# What is the best practise if I want to use a IValueConverter in WPF and UWP projects

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, ivalueconverter

I have a UWP project as well as a WPF project. Both project needing the same converter. But the Interface `IValueConverter` is in UWP in another namespace as in WPF, furthermore is the last parameter not the same (in WPF it is CultureInfo in UWP it is a string). 
So what is the best practice to create a converter for both projects?

**My solution** is I have a netstandard project which has a class ValueConverterBase which defines each two methods from the WPF IValueConverter and the IValueConverter from UWP. It also defines two abstract methods which a sepcific converter has to implement :

```
public abstract class ValueConverterBase
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return this.OnConvert(value, targetType, parameter, language);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return this.OnConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, language);
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return this.OnConvert(value, targetType, parameter, culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return this.OnConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
    }

    public abstract object OnConvert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language);
    public abstract object OnConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language);
}
```

Now I can create a converter in the netstandard project which does the logic. To be able to use this converter in UWP and WPF each project has to create a class which derives from the converter and the specific IValueConverter:

```
public class WpfConverter : CommonConverter, IValueConverter
{
}

public class UwpConverter : CommonConverter, IValueConverter
{
}
```

The problem with this solution I have to add for each converter three new classes. Also every developer has to know about this workaround. 
Another point is that I am unable to use WPF or UWP specific logic in the converter. Does anybody has another solution?

**New solution**

I combined my first solution with the answers from @Anton Tykhyy and @Heinzi.
I created a Shared project which will contain my converter and added there my ValueConverterBase:

```
public abstract class ValueConverterBase
#if UWP
    : Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
#endif
#if WPF
    : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
#endif
{ ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use the preprocessor and share source rather than the assembly. If you want to put converters into a separate assembly, you can build a WPF and an UWP assembly out the same source with different project configurations. `#if` is not the most elegant tool in the world, but it does the job and you have one file and one class. Make a sample converter and have all your developers copy that.

```
#if UWP
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data ;
#else
using System.Windows.Data ;
#endif

public class SampleValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    #if UWP
        string language)
    {
    #else
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // or vice-versa if you need culture rather than language code
        var language = culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName ;
    #endif
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'd add that Visual Studio 2015+ supports [shared projects](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/07/28/using-shared-project-across-multiple-applications-in-visual-studio-2015/), i.e. you don't need different project configurations. You just replace the netstandard project with a "shared project", referenced by both the WPF and the UWP project.